# In Objective c how to define custom boolean type?

Tags: objective-c, c, boolean

```
typedef signed char BOOL; 
// BOOL is explicitly signed so @encode(BOOL) == "c" rather than "C" 
// even if -funsigned-char is used.

#if __has_feature(objc_bool)
#define YES __objc_yes
#define NO  __objc_no
#else
#define YES ((BOOL)1)
#define NO  ((BOOL)0)
#endif
```

Above is how BOOL is defined in iOS. Following the same way i am trying to define another boolean with value ON OFF and did like below.

```
typedef signed char ONOFF;

#if __has_feature(objc_bool)
#define ON __objc_yes
#define OFF  __objc_no
#else
#define ON ((ONOFF)1)
#define OFF  ((ONOFF)0)
#endif
```

When this type defined as parameter autocompletion write it as 'int' instead of 'ONOFF'. But for BOOL type it rightly writing it as 'BOOL'.

Is that possible to create my custom boolean type that works similarly like BOOL in all aspects?

For some properties the readability will be better with ON/OFF, hence trying the above.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**

One quick work around to use ON/OFF in place of YES/NO is

```
typedef YES ON;
typedef NO OFF;
```

But still wondering why i cannot create my own boolean type.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple?

```
typedef BOOL ONOFF;
#define ON YES
#define OFF NO
```